# Where are my files saved in vim for windows

Tags: windows, vim

I have been using the `gvim` command `:w` to save and it works fine saving it to the desktop. However with the `vim` program, when I use the command `:w`, I cannot find where the saved file is located.

Answer (score 2):

It should save to whatever directory you started writing it in (you can see that in the command line). You can also use your computer's file search to locate it and then inspect for the file path.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others: by default it saves in the directory where you started it. But if you aren't aware in which directory you started, then a way to find out is to use the `:pwd`com in vim. This will output the current directory. That's where vim will store the file.

Comment: Good suggestion, also if you save session but don't know where you are (for example if you start gVim on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

C:\Users\"windows user"\AppData\Local\Packages\KaliLinux.54290C8133FEE_ey8k8hqnwqnmg\LocalState\rootfs\home\"WSL user"

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer to get the filename as well.
As mentioned by Cary and Jeen, `vim` saves your file to the directory from where it is started. You can get the directory where it is saved using `:pwd`.

If you are interested to get name of the file, it can be done by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> when your `laststatus=1`, which is the default value.
I usually set `laststatus=2` which always show the filename.